# Visual Studio regex standard and the regex tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

I was posting a question on using regex in Visual Studio 2010 in the Find In Files search window and suddenly realized that Visual Studio 2010 has its own regex standard for this (Visual Studio 2012 uses the .NET framework regular expressions). When trying to find tags for my post I could only find the `regex` tag, but that refers to the standard regex. For lack of a better tag I added the standard `regex` tag but I'm afraid it may lead readers to giving wrong answers when they associate the wrong regex standard to my question. Is it feasible to differentiate between these regex standards with a new tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need for anything special for this tag. What you did is fine:

- You made the title very clearly indicate the context
- You added a tag for Visual Studio

This is more than enough to disambiguate the tag.

If we needed a specific regex tag for all its variants, we'd be completely swamped with them.